# Cracking RSA Chipher / How to get p,q from N?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I have already checked other questions, But there is only use Eratosthenes' sieve or check it from `sqrt(N)`.
So I tried both of them, But It required too much time so I can't get the value...
It's too big to handle in C so I tried using python.

```
N = 1214348893105131924078850286591990112509 #p*q (Key)
e = 65537 # (Key)
```

How do I get the values of q and p ???

Comment: This model of encryption would be pointless if there was a way to solve this quickly.

Comment: But it's professor's homework or something... I guess It suppose to be able to solve...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+1214348893105131924078850286591990112509. I don't know what algorithm wolframalpha used to do this.

Comment: Thank you for comment.  but I have to program it... haha

Comment: Probably your professor's point is that you can't solve this in reasonable time on standard equipment.

Comment: If you're allowed to import code, use [msieve](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msieve/). If not, try implementing the [General number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) algorithm.

Comment: @tripleee And yet wolframalpha solved it in less than a second.

Comment: Yeah may be... but here is Asia and It's the only report in this class so may be not...
BTW How is that link work?
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+1214348893105131924078850286591990112509
It's really fast

Comment: How can I use msieve in python??

Comment: You have to factor the number. There are several methods to consider, however if N is chosen to be the product of two approximately equal primes then the list of factoring algorithms to consider is reduced. In my opinion, if you have to program it yourself, then [Pollard's rho algorithm] is the next one to try. It's relatively easy to program, and is likely to succeed after N\**(1/4) steps, which should be doable. WARNING: You may have to give it a few hours to work.

Comment: Note that your professors may have put a weakness in the modulus that will let you factor it quickly if you figure out what the weakness is. One common weakness in these challenge problems is to choose a p and q that are too close to each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [factordb](http://www.factordb.com/index.php?query=1214348893105131924078850286591990112509%20)

> FF 40 (show)   1214348893105131924078850286591990112509<40> = 34442988190330466543<20> · 35256781043348862163<20>

Comment: While this is the correct result for this particular set of numbers, your answer does not help with providing a programmable solution to the question.